# Python threading doesn't run on cygwin

Tags: python-2.7, cygwin

I'm trying to use cygwin to run my Python code. The script should start a thread and work on it. But it somehow doesn't work. As a minimal example I use the code from here 'http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/simplistic-python-thread-example/'. 
As you can see in the log below the `Thread.start()` ends the Pyhton interactive input in cygwin without any message.
In contrast, on another machine the program runs as expected. I expect a cygwin problem, but reinstalling the Python packages on cygwin didn't help.

Ideas?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 10 2016, 12:56:26)
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time

def myfunc(i):
    print "sleeping 5 sec from thread %d" % i
    time.sleep(5)
    print "finished sleeping from thread %d" % i

for i in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(i,))
    t.start()
>>> from threading import Thread
>>>
>>> def myfunc(i):
...     print "sleeping 5 sec from thread %d" % i
...     time.sleep(5)
...     print "finished sleeping from thread %d" % i
...
>>> for i in range(10):
...     t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(i,))
...     t.start()
...

xyz@mypc~
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten in this way
`cat prova-python.py`

```
#!/usr/byn/python
import time,threading

def myfunc(i):
    print "sleeping 5 sec from thread %d" % i
    time.sleep(5)
    print "finished sleeping from thread %d" % i

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```

works but the output of the second phase could overlap between threads.

```
 $ python prova-python.py
sleeping 5 sec from thread 0
sleeping 5 sec from thread 1
sleeping 5 sec from thread 2
sleeping 5 sec from thread 3
sleeping 5 sec from thread 4
sleeping 5 sec from thread 5
sleeping 5 sec from thread 6
sleeping 5 sec from thread 7
sleeping 5 sec from thread 8
sleeping 5 sec from thread 9
finished sleeping from thread 0
finished sleeping from thread 2
finished sleeping from thread 1
finished sleeping from thread 3
finished sleeping from thread 4
finished sleeping from thread 5
finished sleeping from thread 6
finished sleeping from thread 9finished sleeping from thread 8finished sleeping from thread 7
```

Comment: OK, my fault, I didn't say it clear but it is a cygwin problem! The program I posted works on another machine too. --> Question adjusted...

Comment: My version works on cygwin python. Have you tested it ? The lack of `import time,threading` and `threading.Thread` was causing execution errors.

Comment: Running it I got a syntax error because of the `% i '\n'`. After fixing this problem the script runs without any output...

Comment: No output ? Than you have a system issue. Are other python programs working ?